# LEMP stack with Vagrant - can't install Php5-fpm / Nginx?

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, vagrant, puppet

I'm pretty new to Vagrant, but I'm trying to make a Vagrant setup based on [this](https://bitbucket.org/axocomm/vagrant-wordpress-lemp) using Puppet, but based on Linux 14.04 instead of 12.04. However, changing the VM to "ubuntu/trusty64", makes the installation fail.
As far as I can tell, it fails somewhere doing the Nginx or PHP5-fpm installation.

I get the following error messages after running `vagrant up`, and when I go to the local server, I get a "Welcome to Nginx!" page:

(Let me know if I should post the whole thing, this is just the error messages I could see in the terminal)

```
==> default: Error: /Stage[main]/Php5-fpm/File[/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve information from environment production source(s) puppet:///php5-fpm/php.ini
==> default: Error: /Stage[main]/Php5-fpm/File[/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve information from environment production source(s) puppet:///php5-fpm/www.conf
```

...

```
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Wordpress::Setup_db/Exec[create-user]/returns: ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* to @localhost identified by ""' at line 1
==> default: Error: mysql -uroot -pvagrant --execute 'grant all on .* to @localhost identified by ""' returned 1 instead of one of [0]
==> default: Error: /Stage[main]/Wordpress::Setup_db/Exec[create-user]/returns: change from notrun to 0 failed: mysql -uroot -pvagrant --execute 'grant all on .* to @localhost identified by ""' returned 1 instead of one of [0]
```

(I did try to correct the syntax here, getting rid of the error, but it didn't affect the bigger problem)

...

```
==> default: Error: /Stage[main]/Nginx/File[/etc/nginx/nginx.conf]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve information from environment production source(s) puppet:///nginx/nginx.conf
```

...

```
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Nginx/Service[nginx]: Dependency File[/etc/nginx/nginx.conf] has failures: true
==> default: Warning: /Stage[main]/Nginx/Service[nginx]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
```

...

```
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Php5-fpm/Service[php5-fpm]: Dependency File[/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf] has failures: true
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Php5-fpm/Service[php5-fpm]: Dependency File[/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini] has failures: true
==> default: Warning: /Stage[main]/Php5-fpm/Service[php5-fpm]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
```

...

```
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.
```

Any idea why this works with the hashicorp/precise64 box, but not ubuntu/trusty64?
I'm guessing it's in the setup of php/nginx, but I can't figure out why. My files are exactly the same as in [this](https://bitbucket.org/axocomm/vagrant-wordpress-lemp) setup.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The core issue is a difference in the Puppet version.

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Precise (Vagrant box 'hashicorp/precise64'):

```
root@lemp:~# puppet --version
2.7.19
root@lemp:~#
```

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Trusty (Vagrant box 'ubuntu/trusty64'):

```
root@lemp:~# puppet --version
3.4.3
root@lemp:~#
```

When I provisioned this on Precise I was presented with a number of depreciation warnings:

> ==> default: warning: Dynamic lookup of $mysql_user at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-7de194db6a79aa7dabd1c451463ec16b/wordpress/manifests/init.pp:22
>   is deprecated. For more information, see
>   http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/scope_and_puppet.html. To see the
>   change in behavior, use the --debug flag.

I've forked the repo you linked and committed very basic changes that address the depreciation issues and allow this to work with the ubuntu/trusty64 vagrant box. You can find the code [here](https://bitbucket.org/picklesau/vagrant-wordpress-lemp).

If you just want to see the diffs then look at [this commit](https://bitbucket.org/picklesau/vagrant-wordpress-lemp/commits/c87ca9dd4437a9ef33ab439d59afc1f509de47ba).

NOTE: I've used some Vagrant plugins in my Vagrantfile, I suggest you make use of them as well.

- https://github.com/adrienthebo/vagrant-auto_network
- https://github.com/adrienthebo/vagrant-hosts

EDIT: I've also created this [pull request](https://bitbucket.org/axocomm/vagrant-wordpress-lemp/pull-request/1).